# Python Type Annotations, Returns Type Or None For Error

Tags: python, types, error-handling

What is the Pythonic way to type annotate a function to indicate "returns type xxxx or None for an error?"

I often have functions which return data of a single type -- or None to indicate an error.  e.g.

```
def GoodName(name):
    if name = '':
        return None
    if name = 'Kevin':
        return 'good'
    else:
        return 'meh'
```

If I add type annotations, that looks like:

```
def GoodName(name:str) -> Optional[str]:
    if name = '':
        return None
    if name = 'Kevin':
        return 'good'
    else:
        return 'meh'
```

This appears to state that it is totally OK for the function to return a string or not, but if the function does not return a string it is NOT OK.  It really is supposed to return a string.

The 'Optional' contaminates the type of the result, and any other type checking which uses the returned value has to also deal with Optional.

I use many libraries where functions description is something like "returns a positive integer or None for an error," so this paradigm of None indicating an error impacts a lot of downstream typing.

- Is there a succinct way to say that a function returns a type except in cases of error, which does not ripple through later code?
- Would it be more Pythonic to return something like a null string to indicate errors, so as not to 'contaminate' downstream typing? (or a bad integer if the return type is integer)
- Or is the Pythonic way to throw an error and require the caller to catch it?

Comment: If the function IS supposed to return a string then it should return a string, not None. Optional lets the user know that this function might not return a string and they should handle the case when it does not

Comment: What do you mean by it "contaminates" the type? If it can return None for errors, and you want to indicate that via explicit typing, that's exactly what you want. You want `Optional[str]` to be a separate type from `str` that needs to be dealt with. Haskell's `Maybe` type enforces dealing with failure at compile time, and that's a good thing.

Comment: If the function always returns string, then I can pass its result to a later function which expects a string, without the type checker complaining.  But even if I include logic to ensure the call to the later function never happens with None, the type checker complains that the later function gets called with a string-or-None.  That's what I'm calling "contaminated."

Comment: I see an example of the return-special-value-for-error in the case of string.find(), and the throw-error in the case of string.index().  The value of find's approach is that it makes type annotations simpler.  The value of index's approach is that it ensures later code does not forget to deal with the exception.  Is one of these approaches more common in Python coding?

Comment: " But even if I include logic to ensure the call to the later function never happens with None, the type checker complains that the later function gets called with a string-or-None. " You should give an example of that, because if you are *correctly* handling the optional None, then the type checker shouldn't complain. They pythonic thing would be to raise an exception, usually. Although, what you are describing is a common pattern (one that I try to avoid).

Comment: Note, saying "The 'Optional' contaminates the type of the result, and any other type checking which uses the returned value has to also deal with Optional" isn't really right, it is the *fact* that your function can return `None` that does this. The type checker is merely *correctly* pointing out that your function may return `None`, and you aren't handling that (which is what a type checker should do).

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga's remark about the precise source of the 'contamination' is technically true but irrelevant to the question.  However, his comment that "if you are correctly handling the optional None, then the type checker shouldn't complain" is spot on.  The type checker is not recognizing.  And his suggestion to include an example will reveal why...

    if result is None:
        sys.exit(-1)

So it appears that the type checker is not recognizing the effect of exit.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - If you'll write up your "if you are correctly handling the optional None, then the type checker shouldn't complain" as an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it.  Once I replaced my calls to exit with assert, the issue vanished.

Comment: @KevinKleinfelter generally you could do `if x is None: <whatever> else: <whatever>` too.